# adding swap to google gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I tried to add swap to my google cloud VM instance using instructions from these articles...

https://christitus.com/create-swap-file/

https://redstapler.co/cost-of-hosting-wordpress-website-on-google-cloud/

except that I put the swap partition in /mnt/stateful_partition because that seemed to be the only partition that was big enough and writable. This seemed to work, and memory increased. However... the instructions about changing the fstab don't work. When I stop and start the VM instance the fstab is restored to its previous (empty) state, and therefore swap is not automatically added.

For what it's worth, /etc is an overlayfs. I'm not sure how that goes into the equation.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Rule #1 - Do not configure Linux SWAP. This will consume your disk I/O swapping memory. Add more memory to your instance.

Comment: Well.. your opinion on this seems at odds with the above article, who managed to run his site for free using this hack. Plus to my way of thinking, having swap is insurance against a slight miscalculation that brings everything down.

Comment: An F1-micro instance with a 10 GB persistent disk has a very small quota for disk I/O. Using swap space detracts from available I/O. If your system starts swapping memory, the likelihood of thrashing increases. A 10 GB zonal standard persistent disk has a max sustained read IOPS of 7.5 per second. If you need to swap 4KB memory pages, that is 30 KB second. Your machine will fall over very quickly.

Comment: However, if one were trying to minimise costs, a 10GB SSD is $1.36 a month and offers 300 IOPS for 10GB.  I think back in the day you'd be lucky to get 80 IOPS having your own spinning disk. And yet every system on the planet back then had swap. Because there is always code that runs once, or runs rarely. And there are always occasional users who do something to your system beyond what you expected.

Comment: @xpusostomos I've replicated what you did but my changes to the fstab file persisted, I followed the [article](https://redstapler.co/cost-of-hosting-wordpress-website-on-google-cloud/) you linked, did you do anything differently?

Comment: @ÁlvaroZamora I'm pretty sure I followed those instructions, they're straight forward, so I don't know what happened. Anyway, I've decided to not bother with swap right now, but after your comment, maybe I'll revisit it at some point.